# Treating numbers as strings

Tags: javascript, string

I got bored and decided to make a script, but it isn't working. Instead of adding the numbers, it treats them as strings, ex. 0 + 42 + 0 + 17 would be 042017. Also, the while script goes on forever.

```
var money = 0;
var yn = false;
var bye = 0;
var add = window.prompt("How many dollars do you want?");
console.log("You got " + add + " dollars!");
parseFloat(add);
money += add;
add = 0;
console.log(money);
while (money < 1000000001 || bye == 1) {
    yn = window.confirm("Do you want more money?");
    if (yn) {
        add = window.prompt("How many dollars do you want?");
        console.log("You got " + add + " dollars!");
        parseFloat(add);
        money += add;
        console.log(money);
    } else {
        console.log("Goodbye!");
        bye = 1;
    };
};
if (money > 999999999) {
    console.log("You won the game with " + money + " dollars!");
};
```

Comment: The variable 'add' is of type String because the window.prompt() method returns a String type value. Whatever you add to a string using + will be like appending a string to a string.  [link] http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
parseFloat(add);
```

it converts `add` to a floating point value and *returns it*. Since you are ignoring it, `add` remains unchanged as a string. You might want to replace the new value in `add`, like this

```
add = parseFloat(add);
```

Also, you can just convert the result of `window.prompt` itself, like this

```
add = parseFloat(window.prompt(...));
```

Comment: That helps, but I still need to figure out why the while script isn't working.

Comment: @LouisExley Could you please explain "the while script isn't working"?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the reason your `while` loop is going on forever is because of the `bye` variable. Your logic is broken.

If the user answers No to the prompt, `bye` will be set to `1` and never change back. The `while` loop will continue as long as `bye` is 1, so it will go on forever.

To fix this, you can use:

```
while (money < 1000000001 && bye !== 1) {
```

or

```
while (money < 1000000001 || bye === 0) {
```

However, to store an on/off flag, you should be using a boolean variable, not a number:

```
var bye = false;
// ....
while (money < 1000000001 && !bye) {
    // ....
    if (yn) {
        // ....
    } else {
        // ....
        bye = true;
    }
}
```

Also note that you don't need (read: shouldn't use) a semicolon after `if` and `while` blocks.